# Change background color in dialogs bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a server (without GUI), I would like to create a box message in the tty. Is this possible? Getting the example of `htop` command

[image: Image htop]

**UPDATE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I am using the command `dialog`, by example I want to follow it:

```
dialog --title "Ejemplo" --msgbox "hola" 10 50
```

output:

[image: dialog without background]

I want the background color blue.

I saw the argument `--colors`, but how can I do it?

Comment: This questions need some clarification. What do you mean by "box message"? If you mean that part of your terminal needs to be interactive, then perhaps writing something that uses ncurses would do the trick.

Comment: What you are looking to do is called a TUI (Text-based User Interface)  or sometimes Terminal User Interfaces. Typically built using `curses` or `ncurses` libraries.

Comment: This belongs in stackexchange (it's basically a "how to use `dialog`" with the edit). What you're looking for though is to edit `.dialogrc`; see https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/.dialogrc for how to create a default one, then go edit it (you're looking for the `screen_color` setting, the second value is the background)!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like  [dialog](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dialog/dialog.1.en.html):

> Dialog is a program that will let you present a variety of questions or display messages using dialog boxes from a shell script. [ ... ]